# SSB - Sum of squares between clusters

Tags: clustering, python, sums-of-squares, scipy, numpy

I got a little confused with the squares and the sums. As far as I know, the variance or total sum of squares (TSS) is smth like

$\sum_{i}^{n} (x_i - \bar x)^2$

and the sum of squares within (SSW) is

$\sum_{j}^{K} \sum_{i}^{n} (x_i - c_j)^2 \qquad i \in C_j$ where k ist the number of clusters

and that

$TSS = SSW + SSB$

Correct so far?

I therefore can do $TSS - SSW = SSB$

But what is the direct way to get $SSB$ from a given codebook? Preferablly I'd like to know, how to get there in numpy/scipy cause reading the equations is kind of hard for me..

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq

# X.shape[0] -> observations
# X.shape[1] -> features
partition, euc_distance_to_centroids = vq(X, codebook)

TSS = np.sum((X-X.mean(0))**2)      
SSW = np.sum(euc_distance_to_centroids**2)
SSB = TSS - SSW
```

I think I'm missing the number of observations per cluster, when doing the SSB

```
>>> X
array([[ 2.,  4.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  5.,  5.]])
>>> codebook
array([[ 1.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 2.33,  3.67,  2.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  5.  ,  5.  ]])
>>> TSS
14.800000000000001
>>> SSW
1.3333333333333333
>>> SSB
13.466666666666667
>>> ((X.mean(0)-codebook)**2).sum() # How do I put the "num_clust_obs" in here?
12.542222222222223                  # Obviously not correct..
```

Comment: `what is the direct way to get SSB?` Imagine that you have one centre - this being the total one - and N datapoints which are the cluster centres 1, 2,...: n1+n2+...

Comment: @ttnphns yea, well I extended the example. Can you point out where exactly I'm mistaken. I think I need to put the number of observations per cluster and/or the total number of observations in there somewhere, but - if so - how?

Comment: This question is answered here http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/158210/3277.

Answer (score 2):

Could not find a shorter way, than this one

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq

X = np.array([[ 2.,  4.,  2.],
              [ 1.,  3.,  1.],
              [ 3.,  4.,  2.],
              [ 2.,  3.,  2.],
              [ 1.,  5.,  5.]])

codebook = np.array([[ 1.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ],
                     [ 2.33,  3.67,  2.  ],
                     [ 1.  ,  5.  ,  5.  ]])

partition, euc_distance_to_centroids = vq(X, codebook)

TSS = np.sum((X-X.mean(0))**2)
SSW = np.sum(euc_distance_to_centroids**2)
SSB = TSS - SSW

# The 'direct' way
B = []
c = X.mean(0)
for i in range(partition.max()+1):
    ci = X[partition == i].mean(0)
    B.append(np.bincount(partition)[i]*np.sum((ci - c)**2))
SSB_ = np.sum(B)

print(TSS, SSW, SSB, SSB_)
```

prints

```
14.8 1.3334 13.4666 13.4666666667
```

Comment: Maybe you could write something more and not just paste a source code? If this was a programming question it would end up on SO...

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been trying to figure out BSS for the longest and this matches what R outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The direct way of computing SSB:

$$
\begin{array}{}
SSB = \sum_{k}^Kn_k\sum_{j}^{p}(\bar x_{jk} - \bar x_{j.})^2&
\text{where }\begin{array}{}n_k = \text{number of elements in cluster k}\\\bar x_{jk}=\text{mean for variable j in cluster k}\\
\bar x_{j.} = \text{Mean for variable x}\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

In computation we will show using R first then python:

Using `faithful` dataset:

**R**

```
result <- kmeans(faithful, 2)
centers <- result$center
partition <- result$cluster
SSB <- colSums((t(centers) - colMeans(faithful))**2) %*% table(partition)

# compare the computed SSB and the one returned by kmeans
c(SSB, result$betweenss)
[1] 41538.39 41538.39
```

**python**

```
from statsmodels.datasets import get_rdataset
from sklearn.cluster import k_means
X = datasets.get_rdataset('faithful').data.to_numpy()
centers, partition, SSW = k_means(X, 2, n_init = 'auto')
((X.mean(0) - centers)**2).sum(1).dot(np.unique(partition, return_counts = True)[1])
41538.38830431382
```

Note that using the data you provided, the results were abit different. But the code should definitely work. Also you could consider using matrix  multiplication to do the same thing.