# Computing sum squared distances without computing center

Tags: sampling, sums-of-squares, rayleigh-distribution

Given an even number of sample points in a plane, I want to compute the sum of squared distances from the sample center as part of estimating the Rayleigh parameter.  One way of doing it is to compute the sample center ($\bar{x}, \bar{y}$), then $r_i = \sqrt{(x_i - \bar{x})^2 + (y_i - \bar{y})^2}$ and then I compute $\sum{r_i^2}$.

It would be very convenient if I could instead just draw the sample points 2 at a time (*without replacement*), measure their distance $d_{ij} = \sqrt{(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2}$, and find a function *f* that gives $\sum{r_i^2} = f({d})$.

I've tested a few sets and it appears that $\sum{r^2} = \sum_{i=1, j=n/2+1}^{i=n/2, j=n}\sqrt{\frac{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2}{2}}$ works, but I have not been able to prove this.  Is that equation correct?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158239/3277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By viewing $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and $\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ as two separate samples, $\sum r_i^2 = (n - 1)S_x^2 + (n - 1)S_y^2$, where $S_x^2 = (n - 1)^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ is the well-known sample variance.  So your problem reduces to how to re-express the sample variance as the sum of squared paired differences.

In non-parametric statistics, this formulation is called [U-statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-statistic#:%7E:text=In%20statistical%20theory%2C%20a%20U,producing%20minimum%2Dvariance%20unbiased%20estimators.).  For sample variance, it is easy to verify that the sample variance is a U-statistic of order-2:
\begin{align}
S_x^2 = \frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 = \frac{1}{n(n - 1)}\sum_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq n}\frac{(x_i - x_j)^2}{2}. \tag{1}
\end{align}

If you prefer increasing sum indices (as opposed to distinct sum indices), $(1)$ can be clearly rewritten as:
\begin{align}
S_x^2 = \frac{2}{n(n - 1)}\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}\frac{(x_i - x_j)^2}{2}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Therefore, the quantity of your interest can be written as
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^nr_i^2 &= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq n}[(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2] \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}[(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2]. 
\end{align}

---

*Proof of (1)*. Since $x_i - x_j = 0$ when $i = j$, it follows that
\begin{align}
& \sum_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq n}(x_i - x_j)^2 \\
=& \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n(x_i - x_j)^2 \\
=& \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n[(x_i - \bar{x}) - (x_j - \bar{x})]^2 \\
=& \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n[(x_i - \bar{x})^2 - 2(x_i - \bar{x})(x_j - \bar{x}) + (x_j - \bar{x})^2] \\
=& n\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2 + 0 + n\sum_{j = 1}^n(x_j - \bar{x})^2 \\
=& 2n(n - 1)S_x^2.
\end{align}

Comment: This works!  But what I thought should work requires only n/2 measurements (draw 2 samples at a time, and measure their distance from each other), and this requires (n^2)/2 measurements (distance between every possible point pair).  Is a reduction possible in this approach?

Comment: @feetwet If you inspect Eq (2), you actually only need to make $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2}n(n - 1)$ measurements, which is less than $n^2/2$.  So it already achieves the maximum reduction.